# Как писать на Си в Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Как можно писать на Си в Visual Studio?

Плагина как такового нет.

P.S. Знаю, что есть другие среды разработки, но нужна именно VS.

Comment: А вы пробовали Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Просто брать и писать. В чем проблема?

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight в чате [предлагает переоткрыть и закрыть дубликатом вопроса: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/910203](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47734481#47734481).

Answer (score 7):

Есть две возможности. Первая это в свойствах проекта выбрать пункт C/C++. В раскрывшемся подменю выбрать пункт "Дополнительно", а затем на правой панели в пункте "Компилировать как" выбрать опцию "Компилировать как код C".

Вторая возможность - это создать в каталоге, где вы хотите иметь свой проект пустышку с расширением `.c`, а затем при создании проекта выберите пункт "создание проекта из существующего проекта".

Это все я давным-давно описал на своем форуме в первой же теме 
[Компиляция С программы в Microsoft VS 2010](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-60-00000000-000-0-0-1343465754)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, поскольку я предпочитаю работу в командной строке, то скажу о ней - в ней по умолчанию компилятор трактует исходники с расширением `.c` как текст на C, и компилирует соответственно. Но есть еще и ключики `/Tc<file>` - компилировать `file` как файл на языке C, и `/TC` - компилировать как C все файлы.